Making a cylinder glow


I want to make my cylinders glow like the image but I don't know how to do that

If you want to do it procedurally, you could mix a Diffuse node (with a brown color) and an Emission node (with a bright yellow color) and use a Noise Texture as factor, use a ColorRamp to better control the contrast:

If you want to make the light glow, increase the emission Strength a bit and in the Compositor, activate Use Nodes and Backdrop, create an Output > Viewer, plug a Filter > Glare (Bloom mode for example) between the Render Layers node and the outputs:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
